# bootstrap full width column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I've had this question for a while, yet I cannot find a reasonable answer.

Bootstrap states the following:
*Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.*

But when I have a row and need to place a full width div underneath what should I do? Should I put a col-xs-12? For example

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">Some content here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Other content here</div>
</div>
```

The h1 is full width.

According to bootstrap it is not correct to do this, so how should I do it? Should I place the h1 inside a column or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A row is a single horizontal group of columns, so the `h1` element belongs above the row:

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Some content here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Other content here</div>
</div>
```

Or in its own row that uses a single full-width column, but it's not necessary:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Some content here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Other content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also place Bootstrap components directly below the container, and they will have full width: https://jsfiddle.net/280v7v36/

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Some content here</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Other content here</div>
</div>
```

You should use cols, if you don't know what you are doing. The thing is, that cols have a `padding-left 15px` and a `padding-right 15px`. And rows have `margin-left -15px` and `margin-right -15px`. If you are using divs in rows without cols:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

then you get a problem with left and rightside indentation, if you mix it up with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-...">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore it's always better to do it with cols.

Comment: This may work, but it is not the way intended by bootstrap. As @Stathis pointed out in his question, _Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows._. However, you can place your bootstrap elements directly under `div.container`, and they will have full width. Check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/280v7v36/

Comment: You are right and I am aware of this. I've updated my answer. Thank you very much for your helpfull fiddle!